# Solve linear system with bordered positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, block-matrices

I want to solve the usual $A x = b$ system. In block form:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} B & c \\ c^{T} & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x' \\ x_{n+1} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} b' \\ b_{n+1} \end{bmatrix}$$

where

- $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ is a positive definite matrix
- $c \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$
- $x,b \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, so $x',b' \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $x_{n+1},b_{n+1} \in \mathbb{R}$

Matrix $A$ is neither positive definite nor positive semidefinite.

I am not aware of well-known methods such as Cholesky or $LDL^T$ to solve this. Is there an efficient method to tackle this problem?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo my original question was related to the vector with all ones, but then I forgot to specify it. I can keep the question I posted and keep it general like it is.

Comment: Have you tried using the Schur complement to "triangularize" the block matrix? Then, one would find $x_{n+1}$ and solve the smaller, $n$-dimensional linear system. Perhaps very inefficient.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Normal Schur complement cannot be applied because $0$ and $c$ are not invertible. Probably a Generalized Schur complement may help? But It requires to find the proper generalized inverse for $c$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo OK, I see your point, I have to rearrange the matrix a little to obtain the positive definite matrix in the form like here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Application_to_solving_linear_equations. Anyway it is also possible to use the pseudo-inverse (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse#Types) for the Schur complement, but it looks a bit more complicated. I am going to work evaluate your suggestion soon.

Comment: You can find $x_{n+1}$ using the Schur complement — of Cramer's rule, if you prefer. Then you have a linear system in $n$ unknowns. No need to invert anything.

Comment: If I understood correctly, with Cramer's rule I would need to compute the determinant of the Matrix $A$ and the determinant of the modified $A$ (let's say $A'$) and  then compute the ratio (https://www.purplemath.com/modules/cramers.htm) $det(A') / det(A)$. It seems that the complexity of computing the determinant and the inverse of a matrix is the same (see https://en.wikipedia.org./wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra)

Comment: No need to compute the determinant. The determinant of $\rm B$ is both in the numerator and in the denominator. It cancels out. You can get the same result via (block) Gaussian elimination — related to the Schur complement.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I am getting confused on your final goal. From your suggestions, using Schur complement and Cramer's rule $det(A) = det(B) det(0 - c^T B^{-1} c)$ and $det(A') = det(B) det(b' - b'' B^{-1} c)$. So, if you calculate the ratio you can simplify $det(B)$, but still you need to compute the inverse of $B$. Pardon my ignorance in this topic, but can you be a bit more explicit? TBH, I have discovered the Schur complement after your suggestions...

Comment: Do not compute the inverse. Just solve the linear system $\rm B \eta = c$ using a sensible method. Note that $\rm B$ is symmetric and positive definite.

Comment: I'm not sure about efficiency, but let $x'$ denote the $n$-dimensional truncation of the $(n+1)$-vector $x$. Then $Ax = b$ amounts to a pair of equations $Bx' = b' - x_{n+1}c$ and $c \cdot x' = b_{n+1}$. Thus $c \cdot B^{-1}(b' - x_{n+1}c) = b_{n+1}$, and so provided $c \cdot B^{-1}c \neq 0$ (footnote), we may uniquely solve for $x_{n+1}$ from $c \cdot B^{-1}b' - b_{n+1} = x_{n+1}c \cdot B^{-1}c$. With $x_{n+1}$ in hand, we may uniquely solve for $x'$ from $Bx' = b' - x_{n+1}c$. (footnote) Notice $c \cdot B^{-1} c$ is just $c \cdot \eta$ in Rodrigo's last comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By combining the useful comments of [Rodrigo](https://mathoverflow.net/users/91764/rodrigo-de-azevedo) and [Todd](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2926/todd-trimble), the methodology to solve this system is shown here below. One caveat is that the method is probably not very efficient, since you need to use the decomposition of $B$ two times to find the final solution.

#### 1. Build Equations with Schur Complement

By using [Schur Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) on the original problem, one can obtain the following system:

$$
\left\{\tag{1}
\begin{array}{c}
 B x' = b' - x_{n+1} c\\ 
 c^T B^{-1} (b' - x_{n+1} c) = b_{n+1} \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

#### 2. Compute $\eta^T$

1. Compute $\eta$ using the equation $B \eta = c$. This can be done with Cholesky or similar methods since B is positive definite.
2. Transposing the equation $B \eta = c$ leads to $\eta^T B = c^T$ since $B$ is symmetric. Now it is possible to rewrite the equation as
   $$\eta^T = c^T B^{-1} \tag{2}$$.

#### 3. Combine

1. Replace $(2)$ in second equation of $(1)$, expand and simplify to compute $x_{n+1}$:

$$
  x_{n+1} = \frac{\eta^T b' - b_{n+1}}{\eta^T c}
$$

2. Replace the value of $x_{n+1}$ in first equation of $(1)$ to find $x'$ with regular decomposition methods.