# Conditions to solve linear system with matrix blocks

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, block-matrices

How to verify if a linear system of symmetrical matrix blocks has solution?
I have the matrix:

- $\left[M\right]_{p \times p}$, symmetrical
- $\left[G\right]_{p \times q}$

and then, I would like to solve the following linear system:

$$
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
\left[M\right] & \left[G\right] \\
\left[G^T\right] & \left[0\right]
\end{bmatrix}}_{\left[A\right]}
\cdot
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
\left[\mu\right] \\
\left[\lambda \right]
\end{bmatrix}}_{\left[X\right]}
=
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
\left[F_{\mu}\right] \\
\left[F_{\lambda}\right]
\end{bmatrix}}_{\left[B\right]}
$$

So far, I found this article [Solve linear system with bordered positive definite matrix](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365524/solve-linear-system-with-bordered-positive-definite-matrix) that explains how to solve this problem, and in some steps we have to calculate $M^{-1}$ and $H^{-1}$, where

$$H = G^T \cdot M^{-1} \cdot G$$

So, the restrictions to exist a solution are:

- $M^{-1}$ exists $\Leftrightarrow \det{M} \ne 0$
- $H^{-1}$ exists $\Leftrightarrow \det H \ne 0$

So, I would like to know if there's a easier way to known if the system $AX = B$ has a solution than:

- Calculate $\det M$, if it's $= 0$, stop because the system doesn't have solution
- Calculate $M^{-1}$
- Calculate $H = G^T M^{-1} G$
- Calculate $\det H$, and if it's $=0$, the system doesn't have solution.

For my specific problem, a computational problem, I know that besides $M$ being symmetric, it's also positive-definite.
So, I formulated the two hypothesis to get a easier conclusion, but I don't know how to prove it and even if it's true:
Suppose that $M$ is inversible, symmetric and positive-definite, if $\det M \ne 0$, so:

- $\det H = 0 \Leftrightarrow \det G^T \cdot G = 0 $
- $\det H = 0 \Leftrightarrow \det G \cdot G^T = 0 $

And the last question: does always $\det \left(G^T \cdot G\right) = \det \left(G \cdot G^T\right)$?

Comment: If $p \neq q$, then one of $G^T G$ and $G G^T$ has a kernel. OTOH, by looking at the projection operators, you see that it is possible to arrange the other to be the identity. And hence the two determinants are not equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You find various conditions in Section 3 of the [classical review paper](http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/%7Eliesen/Publicat/BenGolLie05.pdf) by Benzi-Golub-Liesen on this kind of problems, which are known as *saddle-point problems*.